# LastViewedDate SOQL Only Returning Records Viewed By Me

Tags: soql

I am trying to get a sample of which records are being viewed. When I run the following SOQL query...

```
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, LastViewedDate FROM Contact WHERE LastViewedDate = TODAY
```

...It returns Contact records viewed by ONLY me, not other users.

Can anyone confirm this behavior? How do I see Contact records viewed by ALL users in my instance?

Comment: Are you sure you are executing this code in `WITHOUT SHARING` context? You just may not have record level access to Contact records viewed by all users, thus these records are not returned by query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LastViewedDate is per user. You can use it to display a most recently viewed list to a user, and this affects lookup dialogs and search results. If you haven't viewed the record, LastViewedDate is null for you. This is not an administrative field to see when records were viewed, but a developer feature to provide user interfaces that can show the user record they've recently worked with. The LastViewedDate will be different for two different users on the same record in most cases (e.g. unless they coincidentally view the exact same record at the exact same time).

See the [RecentlyViewed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_recentlyviewed.htm) object for more details.