# Is LastViewedDate field is always present on an object?

Tags: soql, fields

We always get an error when we try to query ***LastViewedDate*** field on an object whose tab has not been created yet. As soon as we create a tab, the error goes away.

Just outta curiosity -

Is it like Salesforce keeps this field as disabled till an object's tab is created or something else is happening. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4):

[LastViewedDate is stored as part of the tab](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000315500&type=1). Its importance is not in data analysis by developers, but providing meaningful subsets of records in the UI, per user. See also sfdcfox's answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/199044/lastvieweddate-soql-only-returning-records-viewed-by-me).

Comment: In the broader scheme of things, this is true for many "standard" fields, such as Contact Middle Name or CurrencyIsoCode. If you don't have the feature enabled, all queries will treat that field as if it does not exist.

Comment: Hey @Felix van Hove,
I was just curious how salesforce is managing this thing that till we do not create a tab LastViewedDate cannot be queried.

By the way, thanks for your input :)