# LastViewedDate field not available for Formula on Case

Tags: formula-field, case, lastvieweddate

I'm experimenting with using the LastViewedDate field to create a sort of "inbox" user experience for list views, where records can be flagged for Users who have yet to open and view them. When I try to build a checkbox formula on the Case object that references this field, I get an error saying the field does not exist.

Strangely, I CAN see this field in Flow builder when creating a formula resource.

What am I missing? Why is this field not available for Formulas on the Case object??

Comment: related https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/199044/2602; I'd guess because this value varies per user that it is too computationally expensive to use in a formula field that potentially could be in a SOQL filter

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382652&type=1

Comment: @cropredy disappointing but I suppose that makese sense.

Comment: @TusharJadav thanks but your article doesn't really help me. You can't create tabs for standard objects, so that wouldn't be a way to enable the existence of the field on the Case object. I think cropredy is right -- this field just isn't available for formulas.